# No sound from my RetroPie

Tags: audio

Hi I just setup my RetroPie and have no sound from it. My tv works fine in the hdmi slot I am using, any ideas why I am not getting sound from my Pi?

I get sound on the video previews of games but not in the games themselves.

Comment: To make it more interesting, I get sound on the video previews of games but not in the games themselves

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.